# SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fec <= date and time of de server (no PC time)

Tags: php, mysql, date

this is my first question , I hope you can help me .

I'm doing a system in which I have a table called " fec " on the table " fec " manually insert a date in the format " 22/05/2014 23:30 " the date has to be written manually mandatory ( so I want ) .

I have in the query :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fec < = NOW ()
```

What I want to achieve is : What to put a future date , the query result will show that until you get the date ( tickets to program spans 30 min) .

The problem is : The query takes time for the PC, when the date arrives, shows the query based on the current PC time ( I guess this makes `NOW ()` ) .
So it is not displayed at the same time to all users , because depending on the time of day when this could alter the information users will see some other earlier or later, depending .

What I want to achieve is : the query is `< = the server date` . By this all will see at the same time the post . ( I'm sure `NOW ()` is based on the PC time as changing the time on the PC I can alter the results displayed in the query , this is what I want to avoid ) .

I hope you can understand , it's complicated to explain, I hope you can help me and thank you very much in advance .

Best regards .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL server and PHP server may not be the same so NOW() function may return different time that the time function in PHP.

You need to compare them.

In MySQL run:

```
SELECT NOW()
```

In PHP run:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and make sure they are exact the same. If not ask administrator of server to set up them to be the same.

Comment: If I change the time on my PC the result of the query is altered to hide or show the results, this is what I do not understand, is supposed to NOW () should be the server time and if I change the time on my PC should not spend anything on the website, it is worth mentioning that I'm working locally, but I see that this has nothing to do because if i print the date in PHP (echo date ('Ymd H: i: s');) I returned the server time, five hours more than in my PC. I do not understand.

Comment: It's of course connected to timezones that are set in PHP/MySQL. You need to set correct PHP/MySQL timezone to make sure time will be the same as you expect.

Comment: I can change the time of a godaddy shared server?

Comment: You can do this in PHP without a problem. You can use date_default_timezone_set function . http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php - there is description and list of possible timezones you can set

Comment: Perfect as it was when corrected, now everything works perfect, greetings. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

> ( I'm sure NOW () is based on the PC time as changing the time on the
>   PC I can alter the results displayed in the query , this is what I
>   want to avoid ) .

By "PC time" do you meant the user's clock? This is not the case. The mysql `now()` command will give the server time, which only you, or a system administrator can change. All users will have the same result for `now()` regardless of their timezone or clock settings.

If you want the `now()` command to give a date in a timezone other than the default, you can set it with:
`SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';`

(inserting your own timezone in the quotes)

Comment: If I change the time on my PC the result of the query is altered to hide or show the results, this is what I do not understand, is supposed to NOW () should be the server time and if I change the time on my PC should not spend anything on the website, it is worth mentioning that I'm working locally, but I see that this has nothing to do because if i print the date in PHP (echo date ('Ymd H: i: s');) I returned the server time, five hours more than in my PC. I do not understand.

Comment: This is correct, I saw that the problem is that I'm on localhost, if I change the PC time when the server is changed, which does not happen in the real server as it is shared and not be able to change the time, an apology but I'm new to this and it occurred to me that changing the time of the PC is changed on the server, it was just a matter of thinking a little.